# How to get multiple S3 objects asynchronously into memory

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am attempting to pull multiple S3 objects asynchronously into memory.

For single objects I can use the `AmazonS3`:

```
s3Object = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, String key)
S3ObjectInputStream stream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
byte[] byteArray  IOUtils.toByteArray(s3InputStream);
stream.close()
```

For objects in directory downloads, AWS offers `TransferManager`, but the problem is that I do not want it to write to File/disk. I want all objects to be return to me in memory.

How do I achieve asynchronously pulling multiple objects at a time from S3 and return it in memory?

Answer (score 0):

I have not done it myself in Java yet, but in theory you should be able to achieve this by using `CompletableFuture`.

The second example in this AWS documentation shows how to get one object asynchronously from S3: [Asynchronous Programming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/basics-async.html#basics-async-streaming). To get the object as a byte-array instead of a file you will need to replace the [AsyncResponseTransformer.toFile](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/async/AsyncResponseTransformer.html#toFile-java.io.File-) with [AsyncResponseTransformer.toBytes](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/async/AsyncResponseTransformer.html#toBytes--).

You then need to do that for every file you want to load, and then use [CompletableFuture.allOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) to wait on all the `CompletableFuture`s to complete loading the files.